# Migrate geo data from MongoMapper to Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have models that hold data in MongoMapper this way

```
class WellIndex::Core
 include MongoMapper::Document

 key :well_name 
 key :surface_loc, Hash
 ensure_index [[:surface_loc, '2dsphere']]
end
```

and data is stored this way

> well.surface_loc # {:type => "Point", :coordinates => [-90, 10]}

I have seen in **Mongoid** that you store geo data into an array. and this class would convert into

```
class WellIndex::Core
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :well_name, type: String
 field :surface_loc, Array
 index({:surface_loc => '2dsphere'})
end
```

This way I would have to migrate all my data to a new field since the data is a **Hash**, is there a way I can still use the same Hash data in **Mongoid**?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I can keep the same models with same data as in the previous post but to avoid the error when running tests.

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure:
       error processing query: ns=worker_test.well_indexesTree: $and
           meas_depth $gt 4000
           GEONEAR  field=surface_loc maxdist=25 isNearSphere=0
```

One should create indexes, if you are using rspec you could

```
before(:each) { WellIndex::Core.create_indexes }
```